# How can a planet have an atmosphere in a universe full of water?

Tags: planets, space, atmosphere, underwater

Imagine a universe where the space is not empty (or almost empty) but somehow it's full of water or other liquid.
How could planets still have an inhabitable atmosphere? What could make this "air bubble planets" not crush under the pressure of the *waterspace*?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help]. Your question lacks self consistency: if you have water pressure you have gravity, and thus the water would collapse and not fill the space

Comment: It probably wouldn't work on a planetary scale, but [antibubbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antibubble) are pretty much what you're looking for: a film of gas surrounding a liquid, rather than a film of liquid surrounding gas. 'Antibubble' is also one of those niche words that sounds completely made up, and that's always a plus.

Comment: Liquids are *heavy*. A universe full of water would collapse into the mother of all black holes under its own gravitational field. The actual problem is not how to keep the atmosphere from being crushed: it's how to keep *the universe* from being crushed.

Comment: as L.Dutch pointed out, your question can simply not be answered. Take a sphere the size of the earth of your *waterspace* somewhere in the nothingness of the universe. It would have significant mass and thus gravity. It would just collapse. Just like all the matter scattered throughout the universe collapsed into stars and planets.

Comment: stop smoking that stuff

Comment: A ball of water a little under 3 AU in size (about three times larger than Earth's distance from the Sun) will become a super massive black hole of that size instantly.  An entire universe full of liquid water would be an insanely complex collection of black holes all interacting at the black hole equivalent of touching distance (which is beyond our currently ability to model I am sure).  I can't see how planets would form and remain remotely stable.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to say you can do something with pressure but in reality what you need is a membrane of some kind. Any gas bubbles will ordinarily dissolve into your waterspace given enough time. Some form of very rigid [semipermeable membrane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semipermeable_membrane) could pass dissolved gases in only one direction creating a bubble of atmosphere. The gases once freed from space would help to hold the membrane against the pressure of the waterspace around it. Water pressure should vary depending on the size of the planet the membrane is around as a function of the planet's gravity.

Comment: I like this answer, The membrane could be a creature who uses the one-way transition as a form of filter feeding, which would also limit the location of such bubbles to energy source areas (similar to how planets are usually restricted to area's with stars)

Comment: @GOATNine My inspiration was a short story by Peter Watts in which the crew of a jumpgate deployment ship encounter a planet with a giant, intelligent, living membrane around it, that membrane is super delicate but that doesn't mean such a structure has to be.